# SPFX 1.41 AAD Http Client web part to call secure Azure App Service does not work on Safari

Tags: azure, sharepoint, spfx

We created a Azure AD protected App Service and we can successfully call the service from a SharePoint web part based on the SPFX 1.4.1 framework. Most browsers work, like IE (11 and Edge), Firefox and Chrome (the recent ones).

We chose to use the AadHTTPClient as described here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi

Unfortunately, On Safari, we see a problem. The error that Safari shows is: `[Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored. (x4)`

Any idea what is going on? And are there plans to fix this in the SPFX package? Or is this a Safari-related problem?

Thank you!